# How to boost records with all search terms than OR of all search terms in Elasticsearch?

Tags: boost, elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search

I have configured the default elasticsearch configuration. When I search for "foo bar" I get results which have just "foo" or "bar" on top and the results with both "foo" and "bar" not on top.

Is there a way to boost the records which are having all the search terms than the others.

Comment: could you post the current query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the "OR" and "AND" logic as two queries in a single `bool` query, e.g.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "your_field": {
                        "query": "foo bar"
                    }
                }
            },
            "should": {
                "match": {
                    "your_field": {
                        "query": "foo bar",
                        "operator": "and"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where the `must` part contains the "OR" logic (`operator` not specified, it defaults to `or`) to ensure at least one term is matched, while the `should` part will provide the boost if all the terms are matched, i.e. the "AND" logic.

You can also go further and provide options in case you want to match and exact phrase (with a `phrase` query), e.g. http://marcobonzanini.com/2015/02/09/phrase-match-and-proximity-search-in-elasticsearch/